# Conda build ignoring meta.yml

Tags: build, conda, recipe

I am trying to create a conda package for a tool called [SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/download.html).

With my own build environment things seem to work well.
But I wrote this meta.yml file:

```yaml
package:
  name: "srecord"
  version: "1.62"

source:
  url: https://sourceforge.net/projects/srecord/files/srecord/1.62/srecord-1.62.tar.gz
  md5: c8afebd66c0b4cd2f317567b8e480310

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - libboost-dev
    - libgcrypt
    - libtool
    - make
    - gcc
```

I also have this very quick build.sh script in the same folder:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "${PREFIX}"
mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/bin"
mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/include"
mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/lib"

echo $PREFIX
echo $RECIPE_DIR

/bin/bash configure
make
cp -r bin/ "$PREFIX/bin/"
```

When I use `conda-build name_of_folder/`, I get this error message:

```
$ conda-build srecord/
Ignoring non-recipe: /home/dev1/Documents/conda_tutorial/srecord/meta.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev1/miniconda3/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/dev1/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 488, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/dev1/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 477, in execute
    outputs = api.build(args.recipe, post=args.post, test_run_post=args.test_run_post,
  File "/home/dev1/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 186, in build
    return build_tree(
  File "/home/dev1/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 3079, in build_tree
    for (metadata, need_source_download, need_reparse_in_env) in metadata_tuples:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

The [example](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html#building-a-simple-package-with-conda-skeleton-pypi) using `conda skeleton` works fine when using conda-build though...

Comment: Could it be `meta.yml` versus `meta.yaml`?

Comment: @merv this was it, I am such an airhead ...